# openCV: different results when matrix-multiplication with overloaded operator and without

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, operator-overloading

I have a matrix in openCV like this: `cv::Mat matrix = cv::Mat::zeros(5, 5, CV_32FC3);`

Then, I want to do matrix multiplication in two different ways, first channel-wise and second with overloaded operator.

```
// VERSION 1:

for (int row_count = 0; row_count < image.rows; row_count++)
{
  for (int col_count = 0; col_count < image.cols; col_count++)
  {
    for (int channel_count = 0; channel_count < 3; channel_count++)
    {
      matrix.at<cv::Vec3b>(row_count, col_count)[channel_count] = some_image.at<cv::Vec3b>(row_count, col_count)[channel_count] * other_image.at<float>(row_count, col_count);
    }
  } 
}

// VERSION 2:

for (int row_count = 0; row_count < image.rows; row_count++)
{
  for (int col_count = 0; col_count < image.cols; col_count++)
  {
    matrix.at<cv::Vec3b>(row_count, col_count) = some_image.at<cv::Vec3b>(row_count, col_count) * other_image.at<float>(row_count, col_count);
  } 
}
```

Why do I get different results here?

EDIT: (here an example thx@Frank)

```
int main() {
  cv::Vec3b data(127, 81, 24);
  float ratio = 0.25f;

  cv::Vec3b manual;
  manual[0] = data[0] * ratio;
  manual[1] = data[1] * ratio;
  manual[2] = data[2] * ratio;

  cv::Vec3b overloaded = data * ratio;

  std::cout << manual << " vs " << overloaded << "\n";
}
```

The output:

```
[31, 20, 6] vs [32, 20, 6]
```

Comment: Might I suggest a simpler mcve: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/c1P5GqPGG. The output is `[31, 20, 6] vs [32, 20, 6] `. It's too big of a change for me to feel comfortable just editing the question for it, but I highly recommend you make the change.

Comment: you will have to address it as `other_image.at<Vec3f>` instead of `other_image.at<float>` because your image is `CV_32FC3`. Currently you are not addressing the right pixel positions from your float matrix, because you are addressing it as if it was single channel, but it has 3 channels.

Comment: @Micka it seems pretty obvious that `other_image` is a single channel image.

Comment: ok sorry, then you are addressing `matrix.at<cv::Vec3b>` wrong, because according to `cv::Mat matrix = cv::Mat::zeros(5, 5, CV_32FC3);` it is a `CV_32FC3` but you are addressing it as `Vec3b` instead of `Vec3f`

Comment: @Micka You are correct that OP probably wants to do that, but since they are doing it in both versions, that doesn't explain the inconsistency they are experiencing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCV uses `cv::saturate_cast<>` pretty much everywhere when integral types are involved. You'd *think* this should only change how overflow and underflow behave, but it also has an impact on how floating point values are coerced.

If you want to be binary compatible with the internal opencv code, you need to sprinkle a bunch of `cv::saturate_cast<>` when manually doing operations involving integer scalar.

```
int main() {
  cv::Vec3b data(127, 81, 24);
  float ratio = 0.25f;

  cv::Vec3b manual;
  manual[0] = cv::saturate_cast<uint8_t>(data[0] * ratio);
  manual[1] = cv::saturate_cast<uint8_t>(data[1] * ratio);
  manual[2] = cv::saturate_cast<uint8_t>(data[2] * ratio);

  cv::Vec3b overloaded = data * ratio;

  std::cout << manual << " vs " << overloaded << "\n";
}
```

This produces: `[32, 20, 6] vs [32, 20, 6]` as expected.

**Details:**, according to the documentation:
https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#gab93126370b85fda2c8bfaf8c811faeaf

> It perform an efficient and **accurate** conversion from one primitive type to another.

`saturate_cast` is a bit of a misleading name because it doesn't just saturate values, it also makes an effort to have as accurate of a cast as possible. Think of it more like a `quantize_cast<>` instead.

The raw C++ behavior is to round floating point values *towards zero* when casting them to integers, which is what you want when counting things. On the other hand, `cv::saturate_cast<>` rounds them to the *nearest* integer. This is more numerically accurate when dealing with quantization, which is how OpenCV uses integers for the most part.